# Laravel project on Apache proxy Server only '/' route working, all other routes return 404

Tags: laravel, apache, http-status-code-404, reverse-proxy

I am working on a Laravel project, about which I know very little about. The '/' route works, but all other routes generated by laravel return a 404 error.

I have run php artisan route:list in the terminal, and it looks like the routes are being generated.

The apache engineer tells me that it is not an apache issue, but rather a baseUrl issue.

If that is so, where can I find and set the baseUrl correctly within a laravel project?

I would be grateful for any tips.

I tried forceRootUrl in AppServiceProvider and RootServiceProvider in the boot method.

APP_URL is set correctly.

Comment: Can you provide your `php artisan route:list`  result and routes/web.php files ?

Comment: Have you added allowoverride and other to your apache conf?